# create gradle task in java based plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have a java based gradle plugin that does some common configurations for our gradle projects. Now I want to add tasks like (currently present in our build.gradle for each project)

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = "javadoc"
    from javadoc
}
```

What I need is a hint on how to do this in a java based gradle plugin.

In another plugin I already register tasks using `project.getTasks().create("myTask", MyTask.class);` where `MyTask` extends `AbstractTask` and has a `@TaskAction` method to do its duty. But I'm found no way to adapt this to work with what i want to do with the sample above.

I tried to google for a solution but until now i did not find a helpfull soution as everything i find is using groovy or something similar to my snipped above directly in the build.gradle.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Looks like I found a solution, at least for the javadoc task...**

```
Task javadocTask = project.getTasks().getByName("javadoc");
project.getTasks().create("javadocJar", Jar.class, task -> {
    task.dependsOn(javadocTask);
    task.setClassifier("javadoc");
    task.from(javadocTask);
});
```

this seems to work... but now i have an issue with the next gradle task:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

until now i haven't found a way to get a hand on the `sourceSets` varialbe in Java.

Thanks in advance! :)

---

**response to asettoufs comment:**

The docs you have linked are related to projects with sub projects. What I have are multiple single projects that are not related. For those we have a plugin that already applies some plugins and configures them. so the projects have a common configuration by just applying our plugin.

Our plugin is written in java. And should continue to be java. Now we want to move some more common build config stuff to the plugin - for example some of those basic tasks as above.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:defining_common_behavior                     Can you explain a little bit more what you want to do, as it is not clear... Perhaps showing a little bit of code?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your the source set you can ask the `convention`

```
project.getTasks().create("sourceJar", Jar.class, task -> {
    task.setClassifier("sources");
    // grab the convention that holds the sourceSets
    JavaPluginConvention javaConvention = project.getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class);
    // find our source set
    SourceSet mainSourceSet = javaConvention.sourceSets.findByName('main');
    // user `from` like normal
    task.from(mainSourceSet.getAllSource());
});
```

Some source code to see how the `JavaPlugin` creates the `sourceSet` written in `Java`

Creating the java `convention`
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L266

Creating the `sourceSets`
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L298